# Dirac equation for a Coulomb potential in 2D with NDEigensystem

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, physics, eigenvalues, wolfram-physics

I want to numerically solve the ground state wave function of the hydrogen atom with the Coulomb potential using the NDEigensystem. Here is the code to get the ground state wave function from the NDEigensystem

```
Shift = 10; \[Alpha] = 1/137; n = 1;
Eqq1 = (\[CapitalPsi]1[x, y] - (\[Alpha] \[CapitalPsi]1[x, y])/Sqrt[
     x^2 + y^2] - I 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[CapitalPsi]2\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[CapitalPsi]2\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y]) + Shift \[CapitalPsi]1[x, y];
Eqq2 = (-\[CapitalPsi]2[x, y] - (\[Alpha] \[CapitalPsi]2[x, y])/Sqrt[
     x^2 + y^2] - I 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[CapitalPsi]1\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] - 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[CapitalPsi]1\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y]) + Shift \[CapitalPsi]2[x, y];
L = 10;
A = ToElementMesh[
  DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[-L <= x <= L && -L <= y <= L, {x, 
         y}], 
   MeshRefinementFunction -> 
    Function[{vertices, volume}, 
     volume > 0.05 (Norm[Mean[vertices]])]]]
{Vals, Funs} =  
    NDEigensystem[{Eqq1, Eqq2, 
        DirichletCondition[\[CapitalPsi]1[x, y]  == 0, True], 
    DirichletCondition[\[CapitalPsi]2[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
      {\[CapitalPsi]1, \[CapitalPsi]2}, {x, y} \[Element] A, n] ;
```

NDEigensysem is giving me the wrong eigenvalue and wave function. Here is a picture of `\[CapitalPsi]1[x,0]` function:

[image]

How can I find the correct wave function? Thanks in advance for your help.

**Edit:**
For better clarity, I have included the code image:
[image]

Comment: Could you format the equation is a bit better?

Comment: @user21-Thank you very much. I've added the code image, hoping it provides clarity.

Comment: From the abstract point of view, you are running into a standard problem: Your system does not reflect spherical, or at least rotational symmetry, so by the basics, the approximations in a suqare does not converge to true states. But what its more deadly as an approach are boundary conditions 0 at such a small area. Bound Coulomb states  fall of exponentially. A finite zero excludes the ground state, any approximate eigenvalue are above the first radial knot. But that zero is on a circle.  Use polar representation.

Comment: @RolandF-I have found the ground state for the hydrogen atom using the Schrödinger equation for a Coulomb potential with NDEigensystem in the Cartesian coordinate system. Now, I intend to carry out the same procedure using the Dirac equation. However, I am encountering difficulties in obtaining the correct solution.

Comment: @AminD Your code example only concerns the cartesian case? If yes please provide the Dirac-equation too!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann-The above differential equations are in Cartesian coordinates!

Answer (score 2):

Multiply your equations by `Sqrt[x^2+y^2]` to get a little bit more `Dirac`-like answer

```
eqq1 = Eqq1 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]  // Expand
eqq2 = Eqq2 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]  // Expand

{vals, funs} =  
NDEigensystem[{eqq1, eqq2, 
DirichletCondition[\[CapitalPsi]1[x, y]  == 0, True], 
DirichletCondition[\[CapitalPsi]2[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
{\[CapitalPsi]1, \[CapitalPsi]2}, {x, y} \[Element] A, n] ;

Plot3D[ReIm@funs[[1, 1]][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] A,PlotRange -> All ]
```

[image]